# Meaning of も in this sentence

Tags: grammar

What is the meaning of も in this exchange?

> A:　本当によろしいのですか？
>
> B:　タイバー家**も**ただ遊んでいたわけではない
> 　　先代に比べてはな

I know that も can be used to make something sound milder or less assertive, so that's my best guess here.

However, in this conversation, B seems to be almost bragging that his family hasn't been slacking around. So I'm not sure if the 'mild' usage is what's going on here.

Comment: As compared to "タイバー家は", that sentence looks milder or reserved. So that も is essentially like "*Well*, the Tyburs ...".